# Advanced hstore with postgresql

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, hstore

In my Ruby on Rails application I have some sql that retrieve advanced data and then I convert this sql output to hash and update proper model record. In this sql I have line like this one:

```
hstore(array_agg('some_key'::text), array_agg('some_value'::text)) as  loaded_user_data
```

which after converting it to hash returns me:

```
 "loaded_user_data"=>"\"some_key\"=>\"some_value\""
```

But the problem is that I want to have this hash looks a little bit different. For example:

```
 loaded_user_data: {
    loaded: { count:  100, details: [] },
    failed: { count: 2, details: ['duplicate', 'invalid_external_id']},
    invalidated: {count: 1, details: ['requested by client']}
 }
```

Is there any way to do it with hstore?

Comment: what you want to get looks like "almost json". do you want a json, or some js object or what?.. Can you name it please?..

Comment: Yeah I want it to look as an json.

Comment: Maybe you should look at the JSON types in PostgreSQL.

Comment: That is an app with many data and there is no time to migrating to json columns unfortunately...

Comment: you can add hstore_to_json, like: hstore_to_json(hstore(array_agg('some_key'::text), array_agg('some_value'::text))) as  loaded_user_data

Comment: Well, `hstore` is flat, single-level. You can't have nested multi-level data in it natively. You can flatten nested values to `text` and embed them that way, but it's horrible. You really, clearly want `json` here.